# I cannot figure out how to share a session in a bottle request

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, bottle

I've been tinkering with this for hours now and I just can't seem to find a way to make this work. It seems like it should be simple, and I'm sure it is, but I'm stumpled.

I have one module called 'server.py' that handles all of the routing with bottle, this is the main point of execution. An example of a request handler is as such, I'm generalizing as my codebase is rather hefty and most of it is irrelevant to the question:

**server.py**

```
@route('home')
def home():
    page = Page('home') # A template manager I made
    objects = db.get_objects(10) # This is what I can't get to work

    return page.render(objects=objects)
```

I would like the code to be that simple from the server side and all database interaction done in db.py using helper functions, however I would like to use the returned objects from queries which are still attached to the session and so it must be closed outside of db.get_objects. A session should be created and closed on each request. I could do that manually from home() like so:

**server.py**

```
@route('home')
def home():
    session = Session()
    page = Page('home') # A jinja template manager I made
    objects = db.get_objects(session, 10)

    document = page.render(objects=objects)
    session.close()

    return document
```

I don't mind opening and closing the session every time, that seems logical and unavoidable, whether directly or through another object/function, but I do not want to have to pass that session around (manually) to every db helper function, that just seems messy to me.

I feel this problem can be solved with some OOP, a session manager class or something that is shared between the two, but I cannot figure out how to design or share it. The best idea I have come up with so far is to wrap my entire db.py in a class and have the constructor create the session. That would work for the helper functions, but I also have a bunch of other objects in db.py that also need access to the session such as the following, this is an actual object from my codebase:

**db.py**

```
class Sticker(_Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sticker'
    sticker_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('product.product_id'), primary_key=True)
    sticker_name = Column(String)
    svg_location = Column(String, unique=True)
    svg_width = Column(Numeric, nullable=False)
    svg_height = Column(Numeric, nullable=False)
    shaped = Column(Boolean) # Whether the cutpath countors the image

    @reconstructor
    def _get_related_properties(self, init=False):
        '''Fetches and fills out all properties that are created by the
           __init__ constructor that are not in the orm constructor.'''
        if not init:
            session = Session()
            self._product = session.query(Product).filter(Product.product_id == self.sticker_id).first()
            category_id = session.query(ProductCategory).filter(ProductCategory.product_id == self.sticker_id).first()
            session.close()

        self.sticker_id = self._product.product_id
        self.product_type = self._product.product_type
        self.date_added = self._product.date_added
        self.sticker_name = self._product.product_name

    def _get_svg_size(self):
        """Returns a tuple of the width, height of an svg"""
        # Currently only works with pixels I think. I know it fails when saved as points.
        # May want to improve this for future versions.
        # May also consider moving this function to an external util file or something.
        # Possible units: (~"em" | ~"ex" | ~"px" | ~"in" | ~"cm" | ~"mm" | ~"pt" | ~"pc")
        # Also may use viewbox attribute to determine aspect ratio and set sizes algorithmically.
        import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
        import decimal
        # Set decimal precision
        decimal.getcontext().prec=7
        tree = ET.parse(self.svg_location)
        root = tree.getroot()

        width = None
        height = None

        width_attr = root.get('width')
        height_attr = root.get('height')

        # Get measurement units
        units = width_attr[-2:]
        if units[-1] == '%':
            units = '%'
        elif not units.isalpha():
            # if units not set assume px
            width = decimal.Decimal(width_attr)
            height = decimal.Decimal(height_attr)
            units = 'px'

        if units != 'px':
            width = decimal.Decimal(width_attr[:-2])
            height = decimal.Decimal(height_attr[:-2])
            # Convert to px if not already
            # Currently only supports in, cm, mm, and pt
            # Assumes DPI is 72
            MMPI = 2.834645669291339
            DPI = 72

            if units == 'in':
                width *= DPI
                height *= DPI
            elif units == 'pt':
                width /= DPI
                height /= DPI
            elif units == 'mm':
                width *= MMPI
                height *= MMPI
            elif units == 'cm':
                width *= MMPI * 10
                height *= MMPI * 10
            else:
                raise ValueError('Unsupported svg size unit:',units )


        return width, height

    def __init__(self, svg_location, name='', category='', metatags=[], sticker_sizes=None, active=False):
        # If no name given use filename
        if not name:
            from os.path import basename
            name = basename(svg_location).rstrip('.svg')
        # Create parent product and save to db to generate primary key/product id
        session = Session()
        self._product = Product(product_name = name, product_type = 'sticker', active = active)
        session.add(self._product)
        session.commit()
        # TODO: Handle category and metatags
        # Categories should probably be created explicitly by the admin, and so should exist
        # at the time of sticker creation. Metatags are more numerous and created on the fly
        # and so should be created automatically by the sticker constructor.

        # TODO: Expand the sticker table to reference these values from the product table maybe?
        self.sticker_id = self._product.product_id
        self.svg_location = svg_location
        self.svg_width, self.svg_height = self._get_svg_size()
        self._get_related_properties(init=True)
        # Add to the Database
        session.add(self)
        session.commit()

        # Get sticker sizes
        self.sticker_sizes = []
        # Check if a size tuple was added, default is empty
        if sticker_sizes:
            for size in sticker_sizes:
                sticker_size = StickerSize(self.sticker_id, size[0], size[1])
                session.add(sticker_size)
                self.sticker_sizes.append(StickerSize)

        session.commit()
        session.close()
```

Most of that is unimportant, but as you can see in many cases I need to query the database from within my ORM mapped objects so they too need access to the session. So a simple question, I hope, how can I do that? Can it even be done or am I approaching this in the wrong way? If I am approaching it wrong how so, and could you offer a design pattern that would work?

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution, but for now I'm just passing the session all over the place since that's the only thing I can think of that would work. I've spent half the day on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution and that is attaching the session to the request object which is unique to, obviously, each request and can be shared between modules.